# Wordpress error because .mo files inside WP-Include

Tags: wordpress, security

I had a problem with my previous wordpress installation, actually the problem has been solved, but I still can't find an answer why this problem appears

so long story short, my problem can be solved by removing @include from index.php in the root, the file @include is a .mo extension file, the file is stored hidden in wp-include (random filename like .2e949ed0.mo)

is it malware or something? because after I delete it, the problem is solved immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the .mo contains malware and is called from index.php and other random files on a random path and filename, included in a random comment such as :

```
/*ba725*/

@include ("/home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/xxx/.e5eb56db.mo");

/*ba725*/
```

Are you using an original theme? If yes, can you indicate the name and make a list of plugins in use?

Comment: i think i have 2 nulled plugins, the rest of it is original/purchased/free version, thanks for the answer, i just want some answer why deleting those files is resolve my problem.

Comment: It doesn't solve your problem, at best it solves it temporarily since the flaw and some malicious scripts are still present in the nulled plugins you activated. These inclusions may return shortly.